# jQuery attribute selector using *=

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the following jQuery selector: `$('img[alt*="Robin"]')`. What does it select?

I understand this line of code...EXCEPT the `*` part. What does this `*` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the `alt` attribute needs to contain `Robin` (and not necessarily equal it).  For example,

```
<img alt="whoisRobin"/>
<img alt="Robin"/>
<img alt="Robinaa"/>
```

would be selected, but the following would not:

```
<img alt="Robi"/>
```

More info in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

> `*` represents  a value containing a specific string.

Any image with **`alt`** attribute contains "Robin"

Answer (score 0):

It's the attribute contains selector.

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

`Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring`

Answer (score 0):

It will

> Finds all inputs with a **alt** attribute that contains **Robin** and sets the value with some text.

From [attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing the a given substring

For **egs**,

```
<img alt="Robin-news" src='...'/>
<img alt="xyzRobin" src='...'/>
<img alt="letterRobin2" src='...'/>
<img alt="newone" src='...'/>
```

**Script**

```
$('img[alt*="Robin"]');// outputs First 3 image objects
```

Answer (score 0):

The * matches a substring in the attribute's value. So, images with alt attribute values containing the substring "Robin" are being selected.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/